Unclear reason for terminal collision
I am new to lexers and parsers in general and to working with Lark in particular. I am using the versions lark 1.1.9 and interegular 0.3.3.
I started writing a grammar which produces a warning when setting lexer='contextual' or lexer='basic' - presumably due to regex collisions which I cannot figure out.
As some people aready found out (see below), the warning is given only if lark[interegular] is installed.
Below, three versions of a very reduced version of my grammar are shown.
Two of them work flawlessly, one (of course the one I am aiming for :-)) produces the warning.
Do you have an idea what might be the underlying problem?
Thank you!

Version 1
This is a working version without warnings.
There are two grammar files

a.lark
c.lark

The content of a.lark is:
identifier              : CHARSTR

NUMBER                  : /42/
CHARSTR                 : /ABC/

The content of c.lark is:
%import .a (NUMBER, CHARSTR, identifier)

start                       : idrule   exprule
idrule                      : NUMBER+ identifier
exprule                     : NUMBER+ expression
expression                  : CHARSTR

As for the other versions described below, too, the only thing I do is instantiating Lark with LALR(1) algorithm (the logger level is set to WARN):
import logging
from lark import Lark, logger

logger.setLevel(logging.WARN)

grammar_name = 'c'
with open(grammar_name+'.lark') as grammar_file:
    grammar_description = grammar_file.read()

my_parser = Lark(grammar_description, start='start', parser='lalr', lexer='basic')


Version 2
Now comes the version with the warning of unclear origin.
When I outsource the rule expression to an additional file b.lark, and try to instantiate Lark, the following warning is thrown:
Collision between Terminals a__CHARSTR and b__CHARSTR.  The lexer will choose between them arbitrarily.
Example Collision: ABC

The content of a.lark is:
identifier              : CHARSTR

NUMBER                  : /42/
CHARSTR                 : /ABC/

The content of b.lark is:
%import .a (CHARSTR)

expression : CHARSTR

The content of c.lark is:
%import .a (NUMBER, CHARSTR, identifier)
%import .b (expression)

start                       : idrule   exprule
idrule                      : NUMBER+ identifier
exprule                     : NUMBER+ expression

My problem is that I don't see the terminal collision mentioned in the warning.
The terminal is defined only once (in a.lark) and then imported; the Lark documentation states on the %import directive:

When importing rules, all their dependencies will be imported into a namespace, to avoid collisions.


Version 3
Again a case without warning, but with an additional point that I don't get so far:
When I take version 2 and change the + quantifiers to ?, for example, no warning is thrown.
The content of c.lark is:
%import .a (NUMBER, CHARSTR, identifier)
%import .b (expression)

start                       : idrule   exprule
idrule                      : NUMBER? identifier
exprule                     : NUMBER? expression

In general, I obtain the warning when using the unlimited quantifiers + and *, but not with limited versions (? or ~2..5).

I don't see this warning - maybe because I didn't install 'lark[interegular]'.

I tested it and the warning really seems to be related with having lark[interegular] installed. Ok, In the end it's actually not failing, but a warning. Anyway, it would be nice to know why lark gives you a warning for a collision that does not exist (at least I don't see any).

@Armali, Zappotek: Thank you for checking the problem. The warning does indeed occur only if lark[interegular] is installed and the lexer is set to basic or contextual. I edited the question text accordingly.

As the error message clearly and correctly tells you, there is a collision here, between two different versions of CHARSTR, namely a__CHARSTR (the one defined and used in a) and b__CHARSTR (the one imported and used in b.lark).
These are actually different terminals within the current versions of lark, and it might break your parse if the lexer chooses the wrong one. Lark is currently not well equipped from complex import schemes. Best to only use the import machinery only for terminal libraries, or cleanly non-overlapping syntax variants. This might be improved at some point, but it's not exactly trivial to do.

Thank you for the clarification and the advise regarding the usage of import.
However, a point that is still unclear for me is why the 3rd version mentioned in the issue does not produce a warning.

@xylophone potentially a bug in lark, or an interaction in the way shift-reduce conflicts are resolved I am not aware of - What happens if you use strict=True as an argument for Lark?

Sorry for the late reply. I tested it again (both with and without strict=True) and cannot reproduce the 3rd case. I might have made some mistake when writing the issue (although I tested it multiple times back then, but maybe I overlooked something). I will continue working with Lark and interegular and report if there are further issues. Thanks again!
